# Zookeeper Configuration in solrJ Throwing Read Timed-out exception

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrj, solr6

I am using SolrJ to insert/query solr Data [solr cloud 6.5 - 3 machines]. Earlier I used below code to create the SolrClient -

```
HttpSolrClient server;
server = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("").build();
server.setSoTimeout(20000);
server.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
server.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(200);
server.setMaxTotalConnections(200);
server.setFollowRedirects(false);
server.setAllowCompression(true);
```

Now I configured 3 Zookeeper servers on this solr Cloud. Code to create solr client became -

```
CloudSolrClient server;
String serverURL="zkapp1,zkapp2,zkapp3";
ArrayList zkHosts = newrrayList(Arrays.asList(serverURL.split(",")));
server = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withZkHost(zkHosts).build();
server.setSoTimeout(20000);
server.setZkConnectTimeout(20000);
server.setDefaultCollection("testSolr");
```

I want to know where do I need to specify other properties that were present before [DefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost, MaxTotalConnections, FollowRedirects,AllowCompression].

Please guide how to configure Zookeeper because with these settings, after some time below exception is observed [After some successful hits (read/writes)] -

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occured while waiting response from server at: http://solr6CLoudMachine:8983/solr/testSolr
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:621)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.commit(SolrClient.java:484)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.commit(SolrClient.java:463)
at com.til.damcore.repository.DAMCoreSolrManager.insertContent(DAMCoreSolrManager.java:288)
at com.til.damcore.services.CMSContentUploadServiceSolrOnly.uploadCMSContent(CMSContentUploadServiceSolrOnly.java:227)
at com.til.damapi.service.InsertContentService.insertSolrOnlyContent(InsertContentService.java:136)
at com.til.damapi.controller.insert.InsertionController.insertDataSolr6(InsertionController.java:175)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor155.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:515)
... 45 more
```

Can anybody please suggest what are the recommended production settings for Zookeeper?

I am completely stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vibhav

Answer (score 0):

When you're using SolrJ in conjunction with SolrCloud, Zookeeper returns the name or the IP of the Solr instance you have to connect, looking at your exception the Solr instance is `solr6CLoudMachine`.

First thing you have to check it is see if you can reach `solr6CLoudMachine` from the host where you're running the SolrJ Client.

For example, first try to see you can resolve the ip address of `solr6CLoudMachine` from shell:

```
ping solr6CLoudMachine
```

Then try if you can reach the port:

```
curl http://solr6CLoudMachine:8983/solr/
```

And again, given that you are facing with a SolrClould cluster, very likely you have more than one Solr instance to reach.

So, from the host where you're running your SolrJ client, you should be able to reach all the Solr instance where your target collections are located.

Comment: HI @freedev : thanks for responding. I have already verified that ping is working fine from source machine. This exception occurs after some successful hits.. my bad, i did not mention this in question.